# split file by only lines sep containing "|"

Tags: shell, split-function

I have a huge file structured :

```
>ABC_123|XX|YY|ID
CNHGYDGHA
>BBC_153|XX|YY|ID
ACGFDRER
```

I need to split this file by based on first value on line

```
File1: ABC_123 -> should contain 
          >ABC_123|XX|YY|ID
          CNHGYDGHA

File2: BBC_153 -> should contain 
         >BBC_153|XX|YY|ID
          ACGFDRER
```

Comment: Check out `grep`, it's the right tool for extracting certain lines based on a pattern.

Comment: Is there any possibility that `ABC_123` occurs again, later in the file?

Comment: @TomFenech Yes it's repetitive

Comment: So what would be the desired output if more than one line started with `>ABC_123`? Please edit your question to show us.

Answer (score 0):

This produces two files `ABC_123` and `BBC_153` from your input:

```
awk -F'|' 'NF > 1 { # when more than one field (i.e. line contains | )
    close(out)      # close the previous file (or do nothing, if none were open)
    out = $1        # assign first field to filename
    sub(/^>/, "", out) # remove the > from the start of the name
} 
{ print >> out }' file # print to the file, opening in append mode if needed
```

If you are sure that the filenames will only be opened once, then you can use `>` instead of `>>`.

Comment: Understood, Thanks for detailed. Will try

Answer (score 0):

**`awk`** approach:

```
awk -F'|' '/^>.+\|/{ fn = substr($1, 2) }{ print > fn }' file
```

Viewing 2 created sample files:

```
$ head [AB]BC_*
==> ABC_123 <==
>ABC_123|XX|YY|ID
CNHGYDGHA

==> BBC_153 <==
>BBC_153|XX|YY|ID
ACGFDRER
```

Comment: Useless to a beginner without an explanation, and depending on the number of headers in the OP's "huge" file, it may be necessary to close pipes.